# PDO fatal error - Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This code gets an error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\progapps\addReminder.php on line 12

Here is my code:

addReminder.php

```
<?php

include_once("includes/database.php");

try {
    global $dbh;
    $query = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT * FROM reminder_type;");
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query ->execute();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

?>
```

This is the connection of the database.

database.php

```
<?php

    include("constants.php");

    class MySQLDB { 

       function MySQLDB(){
           global $dbh;
           try{    
               $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME.'',DB_USER,DB_PASS);
               $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
               $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_LOWER);
           }catch(PDOException $e){
               echo $e->getMessage();
               die();
           }
        }
     }
```

Here are the constants

constants.php

```
<?php
$currency = '&#x20b1;';
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "hrisdb");
?>
```

What is the possible cause? And how can I solve this problem? Thank you, guys!

Comment: Line 12 is the problem; you may have a typo in your SQL statement or no call to establish your database connection.

Comment: Probably the semi-colon in `reminder_type;`

Comment: The semi-colon is not the problem, I already removed it. Still, no changes

Comment: Q: Why is `$currency = '&#x20b1;';` in your question/code, relevance? Plus, how are you calling the class/function "MySQLDB"? I don't see `$var = New MySQLDB()` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$currency = '&#x20b1;';
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "hrisdb");



try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . '', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_LOWER);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}




try {

    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM reminder_type;");
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query->execute();
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

if you want it inside a class take a look at this [extending PDO class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175357/extending-pdo-class)

Comment: Works fine here, what error do you get ?

Comment: Did you remove all the class stuff you did in database.php? Copy this code in a file and it works.

Comment: It works now, man. Thanks. Why am I getting that error?

Comment: @JonKirbyJosue Remember to ***upvote*** and ***accept (click the tick)*** if you feel the answer has answered your question.

Comment: You made some class MySQLDB but never created a new instance, but i figured you probably didnt know what you where doing and the class had no use anyway so took the code outside the class. i suggest you read an article like this http://codular.com/introducing-php-classes

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the function `MySQLDB`.  So the variable `$dbh` doesn't even exist.

Comment: It may exist, since he has `include_once("includes/database.php");`

Comment: Possibly, but we can't see that.

Comment: By showing us how `$dbh` appeared in the global scope to begin with.

Comment: Nor has OP shown any code related to using the "MySQLDB" class. Question is unclear.